# Replacing a value as a string with yq

Tags: yq

I have the following map of strings and I would like to change the value of "image.tag" key .
I tried the following but it does not work as I expected. The problem here is that image.tag is a string but I am not sure how to express that. Thanks

```
yq eval --inplace ".spec.chart.values.\"image.tag\": \"$TAG\"" values.yaml


spec:
  chart:
    values:
      image.tag: master
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use double quotes for reading variables from shell. [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) provides a method `strenv` to load variables (also environment) form the shell.

Also by using single quotes, you can just wrap `image.tag` under double quotes to let it be treated as a single word.

Use the [`style` method](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/style#set-double-quote-style) to set quotes for the updated value `style="double"` reflects the updated tag value to be treated as a string.

```
newtag="foo" yq e --inplace '.spec.chart.values."image.tag" |= strenv(newtag) | ..style="double"' values.yaml
```

or if the new tag is defined as a shell variable say `TAG`

```
newtag="$TAG" yq e --inplace '.spec.chart.values."image.tag" |= strenv(newtag) | ..style="double"' values.yaml
```

Note that, if you are using `yq` version [above 4.18.1](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#notice-for-v4.x-versions-prior-to-4.18.1), the eval action `e` is the default one and can be skipped altogether.